# Should we always rely on compiler optimizations nowadays?

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, coding-style, compiler-optimization

It used to be a good practice to write code like this:

```cpp
int var = 0, var1 = 0; //declare variables outside the loop not to create them every time we go into for
auto var2 = somefunc(/*some params*/); 
for (int i = 0, size = vec.size(); i < size; ++i)
{
    //do some calculation, use var, var1, var2
}
```

But now all(?) modern compilers will optimize it for you, and if you write:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
{
    //do something
    int var = /*some usage*/; //declare where you need it for better readability
    //do something     
    int var1 = /*some usage with call to somefunc(/*some params*/) */; //declare where you need it for better readability
    //do something
}
```

The compiler will optimize it to be the same as the first snippet (or even better).

So, should we always rely on the compiler to optimize variable allocation, etc, to write code that is easier to read for other programmers?

Disclaimer: this is not an opinion-based question. I don't have experience with many compilers, and I don't have experience in using compiler optimization options, so I expect people with experience to answer here, something like "I've worked with so many compilers, yes, nowadays they are all smart and we don't need to think about where to declare variables", or "oh, I've run into some compilers that didn't do those kind of optimizations, so we still need to think about it", or something about experience of usage of optimization options.

Comment: My 2¢.  Write for legibility first.  If profiling shows that there is a performance issue, and where that issue is, and manually hoisting some variables will help with a performance critical code path, only then sacrifice legibility for performance... but comment it well.  (And just as premature optimization is not a virtue, neither is premature pessimization.)

Comment: "Trust, but verify" is kind-of my mantra. I write the simplest, stupidest code I think will work, test that it works, then profile to find the sticky spots. They usually turn out to be places I wasn't expecting, so I think on the whole the compiler's are doing a good job. Or at least a better job than I would

Comment: Addendum to tadman's comment (and now answer): The typical compiler these days allocates stack space for the function's worst case right off the bat, so you don't even have to worry about the stack pointer wiggling around as your variables come into and go out of scope.

Comment: The hypothetical answers that you've mentioned are both opinion based, and if it tries to back it up with evidence it's going to be extremely long. That's going to be the case for any answer to this question.

Comment: Worth noting there is potentially significantly different behaviour between define in and out of the loop. In the loop it's going to get reinitialized every time. If the value never changes and thus doesn't need to be reset, you're counting on the compiler to optimize out the initialization. But if the value does change, that's a whole nuther kettle of fish and the behaviour, to reinitialize on ever iteration or not, is vital to get right.

Answer (score 1):

Variables don't get "created" like you think they do. In practice they're either positions on the stack, or registers reserved for a particular purpose. In most cases there's absolutely zero cost to scoping them inside the loop.

As always, look at the assembly output if you ever want to be sure.

If you're used to languages like Python, Ruby or JavaScript where creating a variable is an operation with an actual cost this might be why you're thinking this way, but in an optimized C++ build it's a whole different game, as is with any language that goes through a compiler pass, even a JIT.

Answer (score 1):

The call to somefunc is going to be a fragile optimization away, if it occurs.

But in general, write for readability, avoid premature pessimization, determine where performance bottlenecks are after writing it, and expend effort on measured improvements where the performance bottleneck is.

Code that is hard to read is hard to debug and hard to make correct and hard to improve.  All of which you'll often spend more time on than writing the code in the first place.

Variables of trivial type, like int or double, do not exist outside of debug builds the way you might imagine.  More complex types can have more fundamental existence, in that where you create/destroy them can matter.  But compilers continue to improve, so even here worrying to much without knowledge the code is a bottleneck is a bad plan.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler optimizations are performance safety nets. In other words, they aren't something you rely on. They are a fallback for programmers unaware of penalties in their code.

That being said, you shouldn't trust optimizations by default because not all compilers share the same behavior. In the same sense that no two implementations of anything share the same behavior. If you work in embedded systems, especially on exotic hardware, you might get stuck with a bare minimal C compiler that does very little to help you.

Also, just because something is optimized, doesn't necessarily mean you have to sacrifice readability.